# Insert chart series into specific index location

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, exception, visual-studio-2012, charts

I need to add a chart series into a specific location, such as 5 series available at the moment and i need the latest series be in the 3rd position.

i tried the chart1.series.insert(2,'series(5)') function, but it always return me : "A chart element with the name 'XXX' already exists in the 'SeriesCollection'."

It is due to i have to create the series before I insert since the insert function require the position and the series that need to insert.

Is there any misuse of this function by me or any better way to insert the chart series rather than this?

Comment: Hint: Please make sure to use appropriate tags for you question (I don't think you will use C# and VB). Also you might use something like `Chart` or `Exception`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has something to do that the series does not exist, at least that is not what the exception is saying.

It seems that all names in your `Series` in your chart have to be **unique**. So you have ensure that when you insert another `Series`.

Comment: if i dont add the series into collection first, vb will throw me this -> A chart element with the name 'SOMETHING' could not be found in the 'SeriesCollection'.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with adding the collection, but again: make sure to select a ->`UNIQUE`<- name for the series

Comment: the insert procedure require 2 argument ('Position to be insert', 'chart.series') , but if i add the series before insert, i got this ->  "A chart element with the name 'SOMETHING' already exists in the 'SeriesCollection'."

Comment: I am using the unique name when adding series, when insert I did not  rename it. I will just pick the series.count -1 as the index for the series i need to be reinsert to different position. But, from my understanding, vb might took the insert procedure as a new series to be create and insert rather than moving the available series to the other position.

Comment: since vb took this as a new series to be create and insert, i tried to remove the add series procedure. But i got this -> A chart element with the name 'SOMETHING' could not be found in the 'SeriesCollection'. Thats the reason i am getting frustated.

Comment: Please update your question with the actual code which does what you describe in a complete, short example. I think this will be much easier...

Comment: `Chart1.Series.Add("New Row " & btnYr1.Text & " " & NewRowCount);  Chart1.Series.Insert(3, Chart1.Series("New Row " & btnYr1.Text & " " & NewRowCount))`

Comment: this is the code for add and insert. Sorry im new to this site, i tried my best to edit my comment, i know it look awful.

Comment: with this code, i got the unique issue you mention, but if i remove the add procedure, i got the could not found series problem.

Comment: I tried using index instead of series name as well, same exception happens

Comment: Please put the code in your **question** and make sure its formatted as code. It's always hard to read that in comments. To your code: you basically add the same `Series` into your collection twice, that's why you get the exception.